# Открытие другой базы в VBA Access

Tags: sql, access, vba, office

Подскажите, можно ли находясь в одной БД открыть другую БД из кода VBA при этом не создавая новый объект Access.Application ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Есть вариант использовать DAO и есть вариант использовать ADO.
Для использования ADO нужно в редакторе Visual Basic нужно зайти в меню Tools - References и добавить ссылку на Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (2.8 для старенького офиса и 6.1 для нового)
После чего можно работать с базой из кода. Например, так:

```
 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

 Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
 cn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
 cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\db2.mdb;" 
 cn.Open

 Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
 rs.Open "Customers", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
 Debug.Print  rs.Fields(1).Value 

 rs.Close
 cn.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Ссылка с мануалом на английском, которая мне показалась наиболее информативна:

[Excel VBA - Reference Guide DAO/ADO Objects](http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/dao_ado.htm)

Answer (score 0):

> открыть другую БД из кода VBA при этом не создавая новый объект
>   Access.Application

Если нужно просто получить/добавить/изменить/удалить данные (SQL запрос), то без проблем. VBA умеет работать с ADO. Так что для данных задач  `Access.Application` не требуется.
Для всего остального (формы, отчёты и т.д.) без него не обойтись.

Comment: Recordset я тоже смогу открыть и идти в цикле выполняя какие-то манипуляции над записями? Можно пример, как выглядит открытие базы из кода?